# Exception in setting the dataTable values in pojo class

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2, datatable

I am working on JSF with Hibernate.I have a dataTable in which the values will be retrieved from Database using Hibernate(ORM),

**Problem Description**

I retrieving the values from different table and display it in `dataTable`,
 from the JSF page dataTable ,from an button  click, i am going to set  `dataTable` row values in `pojo` class using `<f:setPropertyActionListener >`
so i will use the values for further use,

- **It is working fine** if i retrieve the value from single DB table
- When I retrieve the values from different table and display it in dataTable, the values are not setting in `pojo` using `<f:setPropertyActionListener >`

It's showing following stack trace,

[image]

I don't know how to do,Any suggestion for this ?

Comment: did you come any further regarding the described problem?

Comment: @L-Ray Thanks for your consideration
, actually by `One-to-Many` mapping i got the solution..do you familiar with hibernate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution that, we can do the saving the `dataTable` values in `pojo` using the Hibernate different types of mapping.

- I have used `one-to-many` concept

It interlinked with other tables so i can store the values from `dataTable` to `pojo`  class.

Answer (score 0):

you are using/have to use a `Converter` to convert the String the datatable sends from client-side to your concrete Leaverecord-Object on server-side. This can be done via

- the `@FacesConverter` Annotation or
- a class extending the `Converter`-interface and being wired in the `faces-config.xml`.

I guess, you try to retrieve a different object-type here, so the former converter just doesn't go into action - JSF tries to put a `Object` in the POJOs getter-method. This method expects a  `Leaverecord` I guess.

Check your `faces-config.xml` for tags like

```
    <converter>
        <converter-for-class>pojo.YourOtherClassType</converter-for-class>
        <converter-class>FittingClassTypeConverter</converter-class>
    </converter>
```

or search your classes for an annotation like `@FacesConverter(...)` and add a proper converter for the new object type.

Hope that helps, else just add comments... :-)

Comment: I hope you are understood my problem, actually i am using xml not annotation type hibernate,so can you just plot with some code any reference link for where to and how to use FacesConverter for **Setting the values into pojo**

Comment: Hi kark, just did. The problem is in the jsf-part, not the hibernate part in my opinion.

Comment: No , i dont mean this, i think u understood wrongly, anyway let me try this.